# Use DynamicResource also in C# code (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using DynamicResource in my WPF project but I would like to know how to get it in C# as well, this is how you use it in

XAML:

```
<Label x:Name="MsgBox_InvoiceCounter" Content="{DynamicResource InvoiceCounterText}" FontSize="15" Margin="10,2,2,0"/>
```

and as an example I would like to save this now also in the string, how do I do that?:

C#:

```
string invoiceCounterText = (how do I get this from the DynamicResource??)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depends where you're merging or declaring the resource. It's essentially a string, object dictionary in the resources somewhere.

If you merge in application then.

```
  var counter = Application.Current.Resources["InvoiceCounterText"] as string;
```

If you define it in the window or usercontrol then

```
  var counter = this.Resources["InvoiceCounterText"] as string;
```

Comment: I know something like this is not desired on stackoverflow, but thanks. You have saved me a lot of work.

Comment: "Depends where you're merging or declaring the resource" - it doesn't matter at all for `TryFindResource()` method